# Generate multiple outputs from a dataframe, reading data only once

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input of multiple files and I need to apply different processing rules and output to multiple files.

How can do it so that the files are only read once, but in a way that I can apply different filtering, grouping, etc and save to different output files?

Something similar to the diagram below:

```
          INPUT
          FILES
            |
            |
           / \
          /   \
         /     \
    FILTER X  FILTER Y
        |        |
        |        |
  GROUP BY A  GROUP BY B
        |        |
        |        |
     OUTPUT    OUTPUT
     FILE 1    FILE 2
```

I tried to use a code similar as below, but it seems to be reading the input files multiple times.

```py
rd = spark.read.format('dbf').load(os.path.join(
    sih_data,
    'RD??{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}??.{DBC,dbc}'
))


out1 = rd.where(rd['UF_ZI'] == '52')
out1 = out1.groupBy('UF_ZI').count()
out1.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .option("header", "true").save("out1")

out2 = rd.where(rd['IDENT'] == '1')
out2 = out2.groupBy('MUNIC_RES').count()
out2.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .option("header", "true").save("out2")
```

Comment: You could eagerly cache/persist `rd`.

Comment: @mike data doesn't fit in memory. If I am not wrong, persist would only rewrite the raw data to disk, wouldn't it? What would the benefit?

Comment: Persist caches data into the memory and disk by default. Not just disk.

Comment: It depends. For a long time predicate push down worked worse for cached data. So it was more efficient to read it twice. Depending on how the input is structured this may well be the same case for you. In particular if the input you read would be partitioned or at least z-ordered by that column I guess it should still be the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, as mentioned in the comments, you can use `.cache()` once you have read the data and use your exact same code. `cache()` is just a shortcut for `persist('MEMORY_AND_DISK')` so your data will be stored in memory if possible, and the rest on the disk.

That being said, it is worth thinking about what you are doing before deciding anything. I don't know about the `dbf` format but if it allows predicate pushdown and that your filters are quite restrictive, it could be better to leave your code as it is to load less data (predicate pushdown on cached data is less effective in spark). If the source does not allow predicate pushdown or if you have many filters, other approaches could be interesting.

For instance, you could wrap all your filters into one job to 1. avoid the overhead of each job 2. read the data only once.

```py
# you could define as many filters as a list of 3-tuples.
# the 1st element is the id of the filter, the second the filter itself
# and the third, the grouping column.
filters = [(1, rd['UF_ZI'] == '52', 'UF_ZI'), (2, rd['IDENT'] == '1', 'MUNIC_RES')]

# Then you define an array of structs. If the filter passes, the element is
# a struct with the grouping column and the filter. If not, it is null.
cols = [F.when(filter,
            F.struct(F.col(group).alias("group"),
                     F.lit(id).alias("filter")))
        for (id, filter, group) in filters]

# Finally, we explode the array of filters defined just before and filter out 
# null values that correspond to non matching filters.
rd\
  .withColumn("s", F.explode(F.array(*cols)))\
  .where(F.col('s').isNotNull())\
  .groupBy(F.col("s.group").alias("group"), F.col("s.filter").alias("filter"))\
  .count()\
  .write.partitionBy("filter").csv("test.csv")

# In spark>=2.4, you could avoid the filter and use array_except to remove null 
# values before exploding the array. It might be more efficient.
rd\
  .withColumn("s", F.explode(F.array_except(
                                 F.array(*cols),
                                 F.array(F.lit(None))
  )))\
  .groupBy(F.col("s.group").alias("group"), F.col("s.filter").alias("filter"))\
  .count()\
  .write.partitionBy("filter").csv("test.csv")
```

Having a look at `test.csv`, it looks like this:

```
> ls test.csv
'filter=1'  'filter=2'
```